# How to access a XML file from another machine

Tags: ruby, xml, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Lets say I have two Ubuntu machine (in the real world they are two ec2 instances) U1 and U2 with ip address of 10.0.0.0 and 11.0.0.0. There is a XML file in U2 that I want to modify from a ruby file that is located in U1 when a new information arrive. I am developing in Ruby and I know about NokoGiri and how to modify the XML I just dont know how to access the U2 from my ruby file.
[image]

Comment: Realistically, the only way you could do this without any additional infrastructure is by mounting the folder on U2 as a device on U1 using NFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up some type of method to access the file, or upload a new one. You have a few different options here.

Access the file directly with something like an NFS share. Instance U2 will provide the NFS share for U1 to mount and connect to. With this the file will appear to be part of the local filesystem.

Update the file all at once. You can either keep a local copy of the file, or download it again before you do processing. But the idea here is that you would update it on U1, then copy the new file to U2. You have a few different options for getting the file depending what you have setup, rsync or scp will probably be the easiest, FTP could be configured as well.

Comment: Thank You for your response how ever I dont have any experience with NFS share. Can you please give an example of using NFS share in ruby?

Comment: Its not something you do in Ruby, instead it involves configuration on your instances. As far as Ruby is concerned, it will just look like any other file. Something like this should help you get it set up. https://theredblacktree.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/how-to-setup-a-amazon-aws-ec2-nfs-share/